# different encoding for the same file on different machines even though the encoding is explicitly set by java code when reading the file

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, ascii, apache-tika

I have a file that my java code reads inside a job and sets the encoding to be UTF8 in this line:

```
LineNumberReader fin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(mutationInputFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Right after this line I ckeck the encoding:         detectEncoding(mutationInputFileName);

When I run the job locally on my mac, the encoding of the file is UTF8. When I run the code on the deploy machine is ASCII.
I'm using tika to detect the file encoding:

```
public void detectEncoding(String filePath) {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filePath);
             BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis)) {

            String encoding = isr.getEncoding();
            System.out.println("Detected encoding of file: " + filePath + " is : " + encoding);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I've added :

```
System.out.println("System encoding: "+System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

to see more and on my local machine it is stil utf8, on the deploy machine it is: System encoding: ANSI_X3.4-1968. The deploy machine uses linux and I'm using java 8 on both machines.

Even more strange is that if in terminal I check the encoding with: file -bi text1.txt on my local machine says: "regular file" but on the deployed version:"text/plain; charset=utf-8".
I managed to set the encoding to be UTF8 on the deployed machine by giving

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

as arguments of the program when running the class.

Any idea why LineNumberReader fin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(mutationInputFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) doesn't set the encoding to utf-8 on the deploy machine?

-- adding a bit more infos
I am talking about same file, let's say file1.txt. I've downloaded the file from  the deploy machine. This file is created by another process that I cannot access.  The steps are:

1. LineNumberReader fin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(mutationInputFileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); -- here I would expect to have the contet file in UTF8
2. detectEncoding(mutationInputFileName);
3. extract information from the file: using fin.lines() and String[] cols = line.split(TAB_SEPARATOR, -1); to get the columns. I'm interested in cols[0] which might have special characters such as ï¿½ï¿½.
4. encoding the signature as md5

```
String signature = encodeAsMD5(signatureBeforeEncoding)
```

where signatureBeforeEncoding is col[0] and :

```
    public static String encodeAsMD5(String value) {
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(value.getBytes());
        BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);
        return number.toString(16);
    }
```

I get different signature on local machine vs dev. I get same signature if I pass

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

as arguments of the program when running the class.

Comment: Encoding detection is not 100%. Also `ASCII` is a subset of `UTF8`, so there should not be any issues. Run tests to make sure things are fine. Encoding can be a headache. Everyone suggests reading [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). Good luck!

Comment: I don't think you have to worry about your machine encoding. I think you just need to know the file encoding. If you know that, read using the file encoding. You can write to whatever encoding you like, given you do the proper conversion. I would suggest you keep using `UTF8`.

Comment: It's conceivably impossible to distinguish between UTF-8 and ASCII depending on the content (because there *might* be no difference/distinction)

Comment: The `detectEncoding(String filePath)` code you've shown will never detect file encoding as `new InputStreamReader(bis)` uses the default charset and so `isr.getEncoding()` always equals `Charset.defaultCharset()` whatever file you read, it isn't autodetected from reading the file.

Comment: Problem is that in the file I have lines such as TRï¿½ï¿½ and on my local machine this symbol are replaced with ?? and it is important to be UTF because I create a signature based on the content of the file. The problem is that on my local machine I have a signature and on deployed machine I have another one because of ASCII encoding. When setting the encoding to UTF8 by passing as argument to the JVM than same signature is generated on both machines.

Comment: You need to be looking at code that writes the file as that is what is determing the file encoding, and then use the same charset for reads.

Comment: *Problem is that in the file I have lines such as TRï¿½ï¿½* That *already* looks like garbage... And you don't show us *how* you're generating the sig (the read op) so it's difficult to help

Comment: Your problem is likely file *writing*, not file *reading*. Until recently, the character encoding for Java file writing defaulted to the default of the host OS. In Java 18+, [UTF-8 is the default](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400) for most purposes. I did not see any disclosure in your Question about file creation. I’m voting to close for lack of debugging details.

Comment: FYI, every 8-bit US-ASCII file is also a UTF-8 file.

Comment: @BasilBourque I've added more information on the description.

Comment: @BasilBourque you got me thinking: when setting `LineNumberReader fin = new LineNumberReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`, my understanding is that I read the file and I say that the chars in it should be interpreted as utf8 chars, regardless of the actual encoding of the file. I am wrong?

Comment: You're dead right. Got to say, again, that the portion I mentioned looks a bit garbagey

Comment: Also `String.getBytes()` is dangerous without specifying an encoding

Comment: For what it's worth: The [Unicode replacement character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) � has a UTF-8 value of `0xEF 0xBF 0xBD`. When you attempt to display that character using ISO-8859-1, you get those three `ï`, `¿`, `½` characters you mentioned in an earlier comment - because those three characters have those three bytes in ISO-8859-1 (and maybe other encodings also, such as Windows-1252). (As has already been said, your problem is likely file writing, not file reading.)

Comment: @anonimos For your last edit adding `encodeAsMD5`: of course you will get different signatures on machines with different file.encoding as `value.getBytes()` uses the platform encoding to derive the bytes that you pass on to the digest. Thats why they only match when you pass in the same character set UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers. You were right, the problem was with the encoding method, specifically with `byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(value.getBytes());`. Changing the line to: `byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`
did the trick so no need for passing the encoding to the JVM.